# Custom navigation bar in Xcode 4?

Tags: uinavigationbar, xcode4.3

I'm pretty new to Xcode and me and my buddy are working on a golf app we tought would be cool to use for ourselves. I've done a tab bar with 3 view controllers and one  navigation bar controller with 2 view controllers. Now, first of all the bar on top is named navigation ITEM and not navigation BAR, so i can't change things like color and button type, all i can change is the title.

Does anyone know if you can just remove that bar completely or just customize it so it's just a picture i made instead? I dont really need it since you could just press one of the tabs in the tabbar to go back.

Sorry if things doesnt make sense, i'm a total noob. Also i tried search the web and all i could find was some youtube clip from xcode 1.2 and i tried it but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your custom nav bar in photoshop or similar, add it as image view and add custom buttons on top of that.